# featherlight.js - prevent resizing on content changes

Tags: featherlight.js

i am using tabbed content inside the lightbox.
When a tab is clicked and the content dimension differs, the lightbox is resized.
How can i prevenis behaviour?
The size of the lightbox should not change after initial load?
Regards, Robert

Answer (score 0):

It's not officially supported.

I think the following would work though:

```
delete $.Featherlight._callbackChain.onResize;
```